# ValueError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Firstly, I created a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('d:\etc\quotes.csv', sep=';', parse_dates = [[0,1]], header = None, names = ['date', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol'], index_col = "date_time")
```

After that, I tried to use .loc to access values:

```
df.loc[:'open']
```

and get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "pandas_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 173, in
>   pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string_with_reso   File
>   "pandas_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 325, in
>   pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.dateutil_parse ValueError: Unknown
>   datetime string format, unable to parse: open

Why? I'm a novice in pandas.

Comment: how working `parse_dates = [['date','time']]` ?

Comment: do you want to see just `df.open`?

Comment: You need to either escape the backslashes: `'d:\\etc\\quotes.csv'` or pass a raw string: `r'd:\etc\quotes.csv'` or use forward slashes: `'d:/etc/quotes.csv'`

Comment: @EdChum df = pd.read_csv works perfectly in my version.

Comment: @Edward, when I try to df['open'] = ... then I receive warning about this staff: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 0):

To get values of column `'open'` between `start` and `end` lines try this:

```
df['open'].loc[start:end]
```

Comment: When I use df['open'], I sometimes receive warning message about this staff: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: As far as I understand, they have 3d array while there is 2d array in your case